# Double if conditional in the line.startswith strategy

Tags: python, if-statement, split, match, startswith

I have a `data.dat` file with this format:

```
REAL PART 

FREQ     1.6     5.4     2.1    13.15    13.15    17.71
FREQ     51.64   51.64   82.11  133.15   133.15   167.71

.
.
.

IMAGINARY PART 

FREQ     51.64    51.64     82.12   132.15    129.15    161.71
FREQ     5.64     51.64     83.09   131.15    120.15    160.7

.
.
.

REAL PART 

FREQ     1.6     5.4     2.1    13.15    15.15    17.71
FREQ     51.64   57.64   82.11  183.15   133.15   167.71

.
.
.

IMAGINARY PART 

FREQ     53.64    53.64     81.12   132.15    129.15    161.71
FREQ     5.64     55.64     83.09   131.15    120.15    160.7
```

All over the document `REAL` and `IMAGINARY` blocks are reported

Within the `REAL PART` block,

I would like to `split` each line that starts with `FREQ`.

I have managed to:

1) split lines and extract the value of `FREQ` and

2) append this result to a list of lists, and

3) create a final list, `All_frequencies`:

```
FREQ = []
fname ='data.dat'
f = open(fname, 'r')
for line in f:
    if line.startswith(' FREQ'):
    FREQS = line.split()
    FREQ.append(FREQS)

print 'Final FREQ = ', FREQ
All_frequencies = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(FREQ))
print 'All_frequencies = ', All_frequencies
```

The problem with this code is that it also extracts the `IMAGINARY PART` values of `FREQ`. Only the `REAL PART` values of `FREQ` would have to be extracted.

I have tried to make something like:

```
if line.startswith('REAL PART'):
   if line.startswith('IMAGINARY PART'):
      code...
```

or:

```
if line.startswith(' REAL') and line.startswith(' FREQ'):
   code...
```

But this does not work. I would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: have a flag, `found_imag_part = False` then when you find the line with `IMAGINARY PART ` set the flag to `True`.

Comment: Do you mean that the file contains one or more REAL FREQ lines, then one or more IMAGINARY FREQ lines, then one or more REAL FREQ lines again, then one or more IMAGINARY FREQ lines again, and so on?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I cannot do that, since the file has`REAL PART` and `IMAGINARY PARTS` blocks of of `FREQ` all over the file. See question **EDIT**ed

Comment: @BillBell That's right

Comment: @DavidC. ok but I think my first comment would work, I changed my answer to reflect the alternate algorithm.

Comment: two questions: will you at any point need to use the imaginary values? And do the imaginary values correspond to the real values?  It might make sense to make an algorithm that pairs them up (assuming they are related) then generates each pair.  Then your program would only use the real part but you'd have a setup that would work for both in the future.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen That's a very interesting point: make an algorithm that pairs together imaginary and real values together. Great spot and brilliant idea. However, in this file, these imaginary values are not exactly paired with the real values. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears based on the sample data in the question that lines starting with `'REAL'` or `'IMAGINARY'` don't have any data on them, they just mark the beginning of a block. If that's the case (and you don't go changing the question again), you just need to keep track of which block you're in. You can also use `yield` instead of building up an ever-larger list of frequencies, as long as this code is in a function.

```
def read_real_parts(fname):
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    real_part = False
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(' REAL'):
            real_part = True
        elif line.startswith(' IMAGINARY'):
            real_part = False
        elif line.startswith(' FREQ') and real_part:
            FREQS = line.split()
            yield FREQS

FREQ = read_real_parts('data.dat') #this gives you a generator
All_frequencies = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(FREQ)) #then convert to list
```

Comment: note that `yield` would only be valid in a **generator**, wouldn't work with the OP's current control structure.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes, I just noticed that and was editing the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thanks for the edit, it improves the answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you very much for your answer. Great idea to accomplish this problem by the use of a function, it is an amazing approach. However, I want to understand all the bits and pieces, that's the only way to learn the right way and not just be happy with the "how to" answer. For these two days I have been intensively searching, but I still don't understand well 1) what is a `generator` and when is used, and 2) what is `yield` doing. I would appreciate if you could expand what these two concepts are doing and give me some places where to learn these two interesting statements.

Answer (score 2):

Think of this as a state machine having two states. In one state, when the program has read a line with REAL at the beginning it goes into the REAL state and aggregates values. When it reads a line with IMAGINARY it goes into the alternate state and ignores values.

```
REAL, IMAGINARY = 1,2

FREQ = []
fname = 'data.dat'
f = open(fname)
state = None
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue
    if line.startswith('REAL'):
        state = REAL
        continue
    elif line.startswith('IMAGINARY'):
        state = IMAGINARY
        continue
    else:
        pass
    if state == IMAGINARY:
        continue
    freqs = line.split()[1:]
    FREQ.extend(freqs)
```

I assume that you want only the numeric values; hence the [:1] at the end of the assignment to **freqs** near the end of the script.

Using your data file, without the ellipsis lines, produces the following result in FREQ:

['1.6', '5.4', '2.1', '13.15', '13.15', '17.71', '51.64', '51.64', '82.11', '133.15', '133.15', '167.71', '1.6', '5.4', '2.1', '13.15', '15.15', '17.71', '51.64', '57.64', '82.11', '183.15', '133.15', '167.71']

Comment: while using `1,2` as sentinel values works I'd think that using `"real","imag"` or similar `str` values would make debugging (introspection in particular) easier

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Ensuring that you understand the question before you write code is good too.

Comment: @BillBell Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for not being totally clear in the initial question.

Comment: @DavidC.: You're most welcome. No worries about clarifcation; that's part of the game.

Answer (score 1):

we start with a flag set to `False`. if we find a line that contains "REAL", we set it to `True` to start copying the data below the REAL part, until we find a line that contains IMAGINARY, which sets the flag to `False` and goes to the next line until another "REAL" is found (and hence the flag turns back to `True`)

using the flag concept in a simple way:

```
with open('this.txt', 'r') as content:
    my_lines = content.readlines()

f=open('another.txt', 'w')

my_real_flag = False    
for line in my_lines:
    if "REAL" in line:
        my_real_flag = True
    elif "IMAGINARY" in line:
        my_real_flag = False
    if my_real_flag:
        #do code here because we found real frequencies
        f.write(line)
    else:
         continue #because my_real_flag isn't true, so we must have found a 
f.close()
```

this.txt looks like this:

```
REAL
1
2
3
IMAGINARY
4
5
6
REAL
1
2
3
IMAGINARY
4
5
6
```

another.txt ends up looking like this:

```
REAL
1
2
3
REAL
1
2
3
```

---

### Original answer that only works when there is one REAL section

If the file is "small" enough to be read as an entire string and there is only one instance of "IMAGINARY PART", you can do this:

```
file_str = file_str.split("IMAGINARY PART")[0]
```

which would get you everything above the "IMAGINARY PART" line.

You can then apply the rest of your code to this file_str string that contains only the real part

to elaborate more, file_str is a str which is obtained by the following:

```
with open('data.dat', 'r') as my_data:
    file_str = my_data.read()
```

the "with" block is referenced all over stack exchange, so there may be a better explanation for it than mine. I intuitively think about it as
 **"open a file named 'data.dat' with the ability to only read it and name it as the variable my_data. once its opened, read the entirety of the file into a str, file_str, using my_data.read(), then close 'data.dat' "**

now you have a str, and you can apply all the applicable str functions to it.

if "IMAGINARY PART" happens frequently throughout the file or the file is too big, Tadgh's suggestion of <strike>a flag</strike> a break works well.

```
for line in f:
    if "IMAGINARY PART" not in line:
        #do stuff
    else:
        f.close()
        break
```

Comment: I am assuming `file_str` is the result of `f.read()` but you may want to be more explicit about where it is coming from.

Comment: [Turns out it wasn't that simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192223/double-if-conditional-in-the-line-startswith-strategy/41192500?noredirect=1#comment69584568_41192223) the file contains multiple REAL / IMAGINARY blocks so both the methods you are suggesting would only work assuming there was one.

Comment: @appills Thank you very much for your both two approaches of your answer.

Comment: @DavidC anytime! be sure to give Tadhg some love since he formatted all this for me

Answer (score 1):

You would need to keep track of which part you are looking at, so you can use a flag to do this:

```
section = None #will change to either "real" or "imag"
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("IMAGINARY PART"):
        section = "imag"
    elif line.startswith('REAL PART'):
        section = "real"
    else:
        freqs = line.split()
        if section == "real":
            FREQ.append(freqs)
        #elif section == "imag":
        #    IMAG_FREQ.append(freqs)
```

by the way, instead of `append`ing to `FREQ` then needing to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` you might consider just `extend`ing `FREQ` instead.

Comment: I agree that `extend` is also a solution equivalent to `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. Thank you very much for your answer, related to the use of flags. It's great. I'm a bit new to the use of flags in python. These two days I have been searching for the use of this new concept and trying to implement it. Do you know any good tutorial explaining the use of flags in python? Also thank you very much for reviewing each of all the different answers of this post, I really appreciate it

Comment: A flag is just a variable that keeps track of what state the program is in (like whether you are in the "real" section of the file or the "imaginary" section) I'd think that tutorials or examples would likely use the term "State" more than flag, [perhaps this would help](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python-state/#h4), but I don't know of any that are simple cases.

Comment: Thank you very much